# Maximum likelihood estimation in a Poisson model for football (soccer) scores

Tags: r, estimation, poisson-distribution, maximum-likelihood, expectation-maximization

I've got a set of football results and I want to make a probabilty model of football scores as described in Dixon, Coles (1997,  http://www.math.ku.dk/~rolf/teaching/thesis/DixonColes.pdf). They estimate the parameters based on maximum likelihood and the model assumes the variables are independent Poisson.

Now I have 2 questions:

- How should I transform my data to input them in the model?
- What packages in R are best for maximum likelihood estimation of this nature?

Comment: Related: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/11800/2970 (including an answer with a reference to Dixon and Coles). There are also some tangentially related questions; see the `games` tag.

Comment: Note that the Maher model (4.1) in the Dixon and Coles paper is just a straightforward GLM. It is very similar to the second model [discussed in the answer here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/15776/2970).

Comment: For American's like me it would havae been helpful in you had mentioned that you are referring to associated football/soccer and not the American game of football where points are scored in units of 2, 3 and 6.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `bivpois` package, written by Karlis and Ntzoufras, uses the [EM-algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm) for maximum likelihood estimation in this kind of bivariate Poisson models (and some generalisations of them). I don't think that it's on CRAN anymore, but you can find it [here](http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/bivpois/).

For more information, see the [description](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v14/a10/paper) of the package in *Journal of Statistical Software* and the related [paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/pdfplus/4128211.pdf) by Karlis and Ntzoufrasin in *The Statistician* (which is a continuation of the work by Dixon and Coles).

The package contains examples where you can see how to format your data. It's been a few years since I played around with it, but from what I remember it was quite easy to use.

Comment: I am having some trouble with the bivpois package. I can not make it load to my R Studio. See http://db.tt/5XZJubGx. I am running Mac OSX Snow Leopard/R 2.11.1 Could anyone help me out?

Comment: This error message occasionally pops up when packages are intalled manually. How did you install the package, @PeterHopkins?

Comment: I downloaded the source bivpois_0.50-3.1.tar.gz from the link above. Then used the install.package() function. In R Studio it's not among avalable packages despite being listed by installed.packages().

Comment: @PeterHopkins: Did you get any warning messages during installation? I tried `install.packages("~/myfolder/bivpois_0.50-3.1.tar.gz",repos=NULL)` and it succesfully installed the package in R 2.15.1 on Linux. I guess that it's possible that this is an R Studio issue - would you be willing to try to install it in "regular" R?

Comment: Ok, the regular R and Package Installer / Local Source Package / At System Level finally got me through. Thanks @MansT for the assistance.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the VGAM package - it has functions to fit the Bradley-Terry model described in the linked questions in the comments.